# JPA - JPQL - DTO Projection For Nested Object

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jpql, projection

Is there any way determine SELECT NESTED LIST OBJECT (subquery) in JPQL.

Not: I don't want to use Tuple or another flat object query, I want to solve in DTO Projection approach.

I have a DTO object, it's called "BookDetailDTO" and its contain another DTO object which is "AuthorDTO".

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BookDetailDTO {
    private Long bookId;
    private String title;
    private List<AuthorDTO> authors;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthorDTO {
    private Long authorId;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
}
```

I try DTO projection on Repository interface like following;

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {

    @Query(value = """
            SELECT NEW com.test.model.BookDetailDTO(
                                        b.bookId, b.title,
                                        NEW com.test.model.AuthorDTO(x.authorId, x.name, x.surname) as authors)
                  FROM Book b
                        INNER JOIN b.authors x
                 WHERE b.bookId = :bookId""")
    BookDetailDTO findBookDetail(Long bookId);
}
```

I get this error message: "Cannot instantiate class 'com.test.model.BookDetailDTO' (it has no constructor with signature [java.lang.Long, java.lang.String, com.test.model.AuthorDTO], and not every argument has an alias)"

BECAUSE "NEW com.test.model.AuthorDTO" is point to OBJECT, not LIST

Do you have any idea?

I want to use subquery in JPQL

Comment: Have you tried interface based projection yet ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Main problem is how to write JPQL query for nested List Object.

Comment: Have you checked interface based projections ?

Comment: @dataminers As you said <new> will return object, why don't use `select new AuthorDTO`, select will return list and maybe work I tried this in hibernate v5.6.10 and got this error: _`Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getDataType() is not supported by ConstructorNode!`_ but maybe work in newest version.